# Regasm.exe, are there alternatives, including Windows API?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows

The software I am currently working on is C++ mainly, including the software installation process. But here comes the time I need to integrate some C# assemblies into our software process, which includes the installation and registration of the C# assembly.

I have searched a few possible methods to accomplish this:

1. Locate "regasm.exe" on client's machine and call CreateProcess(.. ) to perform the assembly registration.
2. Basically create a C# assembly (DLL) and utilize RegistrationServices to create the registration routine. Then export the registration method in the DLL to the C++ components.
3. Manually register the C# assembly. This involves creating a set of Windows registry keys.

I can not decide the pro and con of each method, while wondering if there are other ways to accomplish this task...

Comment: What do you mean by "registration of C# assembly"?

Comment: for instance: running the command line "regasm.exe /codebase my.dll".